# How to write the query to make report by month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the receiving and sending data for whole year. so i want to built the monthly report base on that data with the rule is Fisrt in first out. It means is the first receiving will be sent out first ...

```
DECLARE @ReceivingTbl AS TABLE(Id INT,ProId int, RecQty INT,ReceivingDate DateTime)
INSERT INTO @ReceivingTbl
VALUES (1,1001,210,'2019-03-12'),
(2,1001,315,'2019-06-15'),
(3,2001,500,'2019-04-01'),
(4,2001,10,'2019-06-15'),
(5,1001,105,'2019-07-10')

DECLARE @SendTbl AS TABLE(Id INT,ProId int, SentQty INT,SendMonth int)
INSERT INTO @SendTbl
VALUES (1,1001,50,3),
(2,1001,100,4),
(3,1001,80,5),
(4,1001,80,6),
(5,2001,200,6)

SELECT * FROM @ReceivingTbl ORDER BY ProId,ReceivingDate
SELECT * FROM @SendTbl ORDER BY ProId,SendMonth
```

---

```
Id  ProId   RecQty  ReceivingDate
1   1001    210 2019-03-12 
2   1001    315 2019-06-15 
5   1001    105 2019-07-10 
3   2001    500 2019-04-01 
4   2001    10  2019-06-15
```

---

```
Id  ProId   SentQty SendMonth
1   1001    50  3
2   1001    100 4
3   1001    80  5
4   1001    80  6
5   2001    200 6
```

--- And the below is what i want:

```
Id  ProId   RecQty  ReceivingDate   ... Mar Apr May Jun
1   1001    210 2019-03-12  ... 50  100 60  0
2   1001    315 2019-06-15  ... 0   0   20  80
5   1001    105 2019-07-10  ... 0   0   0   0
3   2001    500 2019-04-01  ... 0   0   0   200
4   2001    10  2019-06-15  ... 0   0   0   0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post exactly your expected output? I think everybody can help you better, my friend :d

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me.
If you want to purely use the FIFO approach, therefore ignore any data the table contains, you necessarely need to order by ID, which in your example you are providing, and looks like it is in order of insert.

The first line inserted should be also the first line appearing in the select (FIFO), in order to do so you have to use:

```
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Which will place the lower value of the ID first (1, 2, 3, ...)

To me though, this doesn't make much sense, so pay attention to the meaning o the data you actually have and leverage dates like ReceivingDate, and order by that, maybe even filtering by month of the date, below an example for January data:

```
WHERE MONTH(ReceivingDate) = 1
```